# Steer SVG Object-Tag from HTML

Tags: html, svg

Community!
Quite often I found answers to my questions here.
Now I have got one, I couldn't solve so far.

I need to steer an **SVG-Object** / Links from within its embbeding HTML-file.

**Set-Up**:
HTML-File
- one div with the SVG-File, linked with an Object-Tag
- another div ontop of it, using z-index, to serve as a menue for the SVG-File.

**SVG-File**: ist a sozi-presentation (amazing thing, sozi!).
You can change the presentation frames either in html using sozi_file.svg#frame01,....
and also in the object tag "object data="sozi_file.svg#frame01" ..."

I want to put up links like "*Frame 02*" in the Menue-div to direct the presentation from outside.

How can I target the ? like the link beeing "a ... "sozi_file.svg#frame02" Frame 02 /a

My example can be found here, no working links so far, just the setup: http://noahmed.de/canvas_test/canvas.html
Mark, this starts at frame 2 already "#f02", using mouse buttons, you can click through the presentation.

## EDIT: PROBLEM SOLVED

Guillaume, developer of sozi, was so kind to answer this question:

1. the object tag including the svg.file needs a name-attribut, as to target this ojbect-Tag.
2. the links need to contain target-attribut, refering to the name-attribut in the ojbect-Tag
3. the href will be like: svg-file.svg#slide02 and so on.

Amazing!

Thanks for helping!

Paul

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a shot at an answer.. :)

You can place function calls in the object's svg file, where the function itself resides within the parent HTML. Each function call will be preceeded by 'parent', e.g. `onclick="parent.myFunction()"` The function can create action in either the Object's svg and/or the parent HTML(or other html-resident svg elements, but NOT in another object)

Does this help a bit?

Below is an example. You can paste this into your own htm file. Also make 2 svg files: obj.svg  and obj2.svg file. This may not be what you need because you cannot click on a link or function in your html that will interact with svg in the object. Of course, **you can change** the `data` value of the object and call a new svg file into the object. This is shown in the link.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title> SVG in Object : parent.functions</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body style='padding:10px;font-family:arial'>
<center>
<h4>SVG in Object : parent.functions</h4>
<div style='width:90%;background-color:gainsboro;text-align:justify;padding:10px;border-radius:6px;'>
SVG within an Object can include function calls that are resident in the parent HTML.  These functions can perform actions in either the parent html document and/or within the object.
</div>
<div style='width:400px;height:400px;background-color:lightgreen'>
<object data="obj.svg" type="image/svg+xml" id="objsvg" width="400" height="400"></object><br />
</div><br />
<i>Click on element to turn its fill color to orange</i><br /><br />
<a href=javascript:changeObjData()>Change Object Data</a><br /><br />
&lt;object data="obj.svg" type="image/svg+xml" width="400" height="400"&gt;&lt;/object&gt;
<br />Javascript:<br />
<textarea id=jsValue style='border-radius:26px;font-size:110%;font-weight:bold;color:midnightblue;padding:16px;background-color:beige;border-width:0px;font-size:100%;font-family:lucida console;width:90%;height:400px'></textarea>
</center>
<div id='browserDiv' style='padding:5px;position:absolute;top:5px;left:5px;background-color:gainsboro;'>OK in:IE11/CH32/FF23<br /></div>
<script id=myScript>
/*  obj.svg file
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="400" height="400">
<circle onclick="parent.clickMe(evt)" id="myCircle" cx="100" cy="100" fill="blue" r="80" />
<rect onclick="parent.clickMe(evt)" id="myRect" x="200" y="200" fill="red" width="200" height="100" />
</svg>
*/

/*  obj2.svg file
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="400" height="400">
<circle  id="myCircle1" cx="50" cy="100" fill="blue" r="20" />
<circle  id="myCircle2" cx="100" cy="50" fill="green" r="20" />
<circle  id="myCircle3" cx="300" cy="100" fill="red" r="20" />
<circle  id="myCircle4" cx="200" cy="300" fill="orange" r="20" />
</svg>
*/
//---click within circle/rect element in the object---
function clickMe(evt)
{
   var target=evt.target
   target.setAttribute("fill","orange")
}
//--link---
function changeObjData()
{
   objsvg.data="obj2.svg"
}

</script>
<script>
document.addEventListener("onload",init(),false)
function init()
{
    jsValue.value=myScript.text

}
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It sounds very much worth a shot - however, I am not an expert. Could you for the sake of my lack of knowledge give me a more concrete example on how to handle this in my example? I.e. what function I would apply to my links for them to call the function written into the objects SVG? Thanks in advance, Francis.

Comment: See EDIT above - I want to be able to click on the link/text/btn in the parent html to cause the embedded *.svg to change. Is there a way?